# Has 'Include' or 'Include_once' changed with PHP5.5 since PHP5.1?

Tags: php

I have just revisited some code I wrote a year ago that worked fine with PHP5.1, but now does not work with PHP5.5, help would be appreciated.

I have a dbconfig.php file:

```
<?php
$dbtype = "mysql";
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'SmartyUser';
$dbpass = 'pa55';
$dbname = 'test';
$dbtable = 'pagesetup';
$DOCUMENT_ROOT = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
define( "HOMEPAGE_NUM_ARTICLES", 5 );
define( "DB_DSN", "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test" );
define( "TEMPLATE_PATH", "CMStemplates" );
ini_set( "display_errors", true );
date_default_timezone_set( "Australia/Brisbane" );
?>
```

I used to 'include' it in several files. However I get complaints now that "**Notice: Constant HOMEPAGE_NUM_ARTICLES already defined in C:\wamp2\www\SOURCE CODE\Pottsville\dbconfig.php on line 10**"

If I `include_once` or `require_once` I get complaints "**Notice: Undefined variable: dbhost**" ...

```
include( 'dbconfig.php' );
try
{
    $this->objMyPDO=new PDO('mysql:host=' . $dbhost . ';dbname=' . $dbname , $dbuser, $dbpass);
}
```

... any thoughts?

Comment: You're missing a closing quote here: `$dbname = 'test;`

Comment: I think that you have started to see notices.

Comment: Sorry, that was my typo in copy\paste and trying to hide the name of the database. The live code has the closing quote.

Comment: Both your error messages are just  `notice`s, and you are on a new PHP installation. That situation leads me to assume that on your previous PHP installation you had notice messages suppressed and kept writing your code. Now this new installation doesn't suppress those messages and you are getting them. The first thing to check is where are you including the files and how many times :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have scope problems, so if you `include` the file multiple times it will fail, but it you `include_once` when you're on a different scope file won't be included. I think if you continue using `include` and check for the constants in `config.php` it will work:

```
<?php
$dbtype = "mysql";
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'SmartyUser';
$dbpass = 'pa55';
$dbname = 'test';
$dbtable = 'pagesetup';
$DOCUMENT_ROOT = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
if(!defined("HOMEPAGE_NUM_ARTICLES")) define( "HOMEPAGE_NUM_ARTICLES", 5 );
if(!defined("DB_DSN")) define( "DB_DSN", "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test" );
if(!defined("TEMPLATE_PATH")) define( "TEMPLATE_PATH", "CMStemplates" );
ini_set( "display_errors", true );
date_default_timezone_set( "Australia/Brisbane" );
?>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Actually, including the file multiple times doesn't fail; it just shows a notice ... which depends on configuration rather than php version :)

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me how to check for the constants in config.php? I have not done this before.

Comment: @user2514675, sure just review the code I've post, use the `defined` function. For your reference [link]http://es1.php.net/manual/es/function.defined.php[link].

Answer (score 0):

`include_once` and `require_once` has not changed from past php versions. the only thing is while you've a DB connection file, that cannot be included once, it has to be directly included. using `include` or `require`

Comment: you can try checking the conditions for the constants if not defined define it.